# Keep just the last 10 characters of a line

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I have a file which is as following

```
!J INCé0001438823
#1 A LIFESAFER HOLDINGS, INC.é0001509607
#1 ARIZONA DISCOUNT PROPERTIES LLCé0001457512
#1 PAINTBALL CORPé0001433777
$ LLCé0001427189
$AVY, INC.é0001655250
& S MEDIA GROUP LLCé0001447162
```

I just want to keep the last 10 characters of each line so that it becomes as following:-

```
0001438823
0001509607
0001457512
0001433777
0001427189
0001655250
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/.*\(.\{10\}\)/\1
:                     ex-commaned
 %                    entire file
  s/                  substitute
    .*                anything (greedy)
        .             followed by any character
         \{10\}       exactly 10 of them
      \(       \)     put them in a match group
                 /    replace with
                  \1  said match group
```

Answer (score 5):

I would treat this as a shell script problem. Enter the following in vim:

```
:%! rev|cut -c1-10|rev
```

The `:%!` will pipe the entire buffer through the following filter, and then the filter comes straight from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550235/print-last-n-characters-from-all-lines-in-a-file-using-cut).

Answer (score 3):

for a single line you could use:

```
$9hd0
$       go to end of line
 9h     go 9 characters left
   d0   delete to beginning of line
```

Comment: and to apply it to all lines `:%norm $9hd0`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `é` character appears only once in a line, and only before your target ten digits, then this would seem to work:

```
:% s/^.*é//

:             command
 %            all lines
   s/    /    substitute (i.e., search-and-replace) the stuff between / and /
     ^        search from beginning of line,
      .       including any character (wildcard),
       *      any number of the preceding character,
        é     finding "é";
         //   replace with the stuff between / and / (i.e., nothing)
```

Note that you can type the `é` character by using `ctrl-k e'` (control-k, then e, then apostrophe, without spaces).  On my system at least, this works in insert mode and when typing the "substitute" command.  (To see the list of characters you can invoke with the `ctrl-k` "digraph" feature, use `:dig` or `:digraph`.